# Jquery by form by class

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have few forms in a page. Each type of input have a different class. If it is going to be an integer the class is going to be integer. The problem is when i try it to validate. It validates all the forms that have input class integer.

How i can fix to validate only the input change in the form?

```
$(".integer").change(function() {
    validateInteger($(".integer"));
});
```

Comment: `validateInteger($(this))`. But `<input type="number">` would help you better.

Comment: Unless, like me, you need to support < IE10. http://caniuse.com/#search=input%20type%3D%22number%22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery website:

> `this` is a special keyword that is used in methods to refer to the
>   object on which a method is being invoked.

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

So, you're setting up a  handler so whenever a value changes for any element with the class `integer` - then do `function`.  Within `function`, `this` will refer to the element that was changed. `$(this)` will provide you the affected element with the extra jQuery functionality.

```
$(".integer").change(function() {
    validateInteger($(this));
});
```